# How to enforce 80 columns in latex using emacs

Tags: emacs, latex, indentation

I see that fill column shows a nice bar at the point that I want.

This is great.

But I'm lazy. I would like it to automatically hit return for me. Not to mention that sometimes I go back to edit stuff and my 80 columns rule gets everything messy.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn on `auto-fill-mode`:

```
(setf fill-column 80)
(add-hook 'latex-mode-hook #'auto-fill-mode)
```

> When Auto Fill mode is enabled, inserting a space at a column
>   beyond `current-fill-column' automatically breaks the line at a
>   previous space.

If you go back to edit code later, simply `M-q` (`fill-paragraph`) to rewrap.